# How to pass data from one page to other page in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

I have created a new blog project using angular-js. Here I have one page listing all the blogs and if I click on the edit button or delete button, I want to move to next page and show that data in the form from where I updated the blog.

My blog list page: listblog.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>



    <title>My First AngularJs Blog</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/blog-home.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body ng-app="blogapp">

    <!-- Navigation -->
   <div ng-include="'includes/header.html'">                    
</div>

    <!-- Page Content -->



       <div class="container">
 <div ng-controller="blogcontroller">
  <h2>Blog List</h2>
  <p>Here is the awsome blog list</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Blog</th>
        <th>Posted On</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr  ng-repeat="blg in allblog">
        <td>{{blg.title}}</td>
        <td>{{blg.description}}</td>
        <td>{{blg.created_on }}</td>
        <td><a href="">Edit</a> || <a href="">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  </div>
</div>


        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->

 <div ng-include="'includes/footer.html'">                    
</div>

    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

I want to create a controller for edit.
My Controller file: controller.js

```
var myApp = angular.module("blogapp", []);

  myApp.controller('blogcontroller',function ($scope,$http){

    $http({method: 'GET' , url: 'getallblog.php'}).success(function(data){
        $scope.allblog = data;
    });


    $scope.new_post =function(){



    $http.post("addblog.php" ,{'title' : $scope.title ,'description' : $scope.description }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        window.location='index.html';
        console.log("inserted Successfully");
    });
  } ;


  $scope.editpost = function(index){

    $http.post('allscript.php?action=edit_post', { 'id' : index})
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config){


    }) 
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config){
           console.log(status);
        });


  }

  });
```

---

And my php script page where all operations are performed
allscript.php

```
<?php 

$user ="root";
$pass ="m2n1shlko";

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog_db', $user, $pass);


switch($_GET['action']){

    case 'edit_post':
        edit_post();
    break;





function edit_post(){

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));     
    $index = $data->id; 

$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM blog_list where id='$index'") ;
$da = $query->execute();
$getre = $da->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r(json_encode($getre));
return $getre;


}



}
?>
```

I am new in angular-js. I don't know how to get the ID of that record and to take to the next page for edit/update/delete.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Using Angular, you're not supposed to wipe everything out and change page completely. Angular has a [templating system](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates) that encourages one-page apps, while _looking like_ you're on a different page. But in reality, the content is dynamically loaded in the same page, only the hash in the URL changes. This way, you keep all your data and your controllers in one page. Problem solved.

Comment: Go through tutorial on angular documentation site. Will show you how routing basics work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the @Jeremy Thille is right... Please check angular ngRoute module for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07.
 Also the good practice is to refactor all of your connections/post/get in factories/services, and to inject them directly on your controllers (where you needs of them) http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

you can use to save data between different page
`$window.sessionStorage`